# Shared objects with mmap?

Tags: python, shared-memory, mmap

I have a web application with 2+ worker processes (Gunicorn). Each of them loads its own copy of read-only cache -- different and complex MongoEngine models.

Is there a way to put all this cache data into a memory location which can be shared by all workers?

Like using `mmap` and creating a bunch a model instances their `__dict__` pointing to a location in the shared memory?

Is this possible?

Comment: The only kind of data `mmap` supports is `bytearray`, so using it to share other kinds of objects would be difficult at best, if not impossible.